# how to get JPanel with RectangularShape in JPanel to paint

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm having an issue with drawing RectangularShapes Or Shapes. I need to have this within the actual Panel instead of within the Frame because I need that kind of flexibility. But I keep on getting stuck. I haven't been well trained in GUI with any language so feedback is much appreciated.

Code is below, Please help me find out why this isn't working, and how I can get it to work.

```
public class GUI_Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GUI_Test gui = new GUI_Test();
        gui.tryBasic();
    }


    public void tryBasic()
    {
        JFrame MyFrame = new JFrame();
        MyFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyFrame.setSize(800, 500);
        MyFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // This won't work and can't figure out why!!!!
        // The button appears but not the Ellipse.
        JPanel JP = new JPanel();
        JButton btn3 = new JButton("This is a button");
        JP.add(new MyGUIObject(new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 70, 100, 100), Color.red));
        JP.add(btn3);
        MyFrame.getContentPane().add(JP);

        // This works but I need it in a panel for easier control 
        //MyFrame.add(new MyGUIObject(new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 70, 100, 100), Color.blue));

        // This of course works.
        //MyFrame.getContentPane().add(new MyGUIObject(new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 70, 100, 100), Color.green));

        MyFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public class MyGUIObject extends JPanel
    {
        protected RectangularShape RecObj;
        protected Color myColor;    
        public MyGUIObject(RectangularShape SetShape, Color setColor)
        {
            RecObj = SetShape;
            myColor = setColor;
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setPaint(myColor);
            g2d.fill(RecObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't compile. Missing imports and RectangularShape definition.

Comment: Should be ok with importing java.awt.geom.RectangularShape;

Comment: `paintComponent` should cal `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting.  Personally, I use `setColor` instead of `setPaint`, but that's me

Comment: Also, some explanation of the actual problem you're having might be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main problems I can see.

1. You're not calling `super.paintComponent` from your `paintComponent` method, this is going to cause some interesting, but nasty paint artefacts
2. `JPanel` use a `FlowLayout` by default, where the `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout`, this is further complicated by...
3. You don't provide any sizing hints for the `MyGUIObject` class, so the `FlowLayout` will use the `JPanel`'s default `preferredSize`, which is `0x0` when it calculates the layout for the `JPanel`.

First, call `super.paintComponent` from your `paintComponent` method and override the `getPreferredSize` method

```
public class MyGUIObject extends JPanel {

    protected RectangularShape RecObj;
    protected Color myColor;

    public MyGUIObject(RectangularShape SetShape, Color setColor) {
        RecObj = SetShape;
        myColor = setColor;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setPaint(myColor);
        g2d.fill(RecObj);
    }
}
```

Next, change the layout that the `JPanel` is using to something like `BorderLayout` (although the default `FlowLayout` will work, `BorderLayout` will give you a little more control)

```
JPanel JP = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JButton btn3 = new JButton("This is a button");
JP.add(new MyGUIObject(new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 70, 100, 100), Color.red));
JP.add(btn3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
MyFrame.getContentPane().add(JP);
```

Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you so much! I am blown away, this works PERFECTLY. I threw this into my larger bit of code with mouse handlers and it worked, and amazing additions to it too. Thank you so much. GetPerferredSize() was exactly what it needed, The Super.paintComponent() is perfect, and something I hadn't thought of. I'm going to read up on a lot of this. AMAZING information, and I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public class GUI_Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI_Test gui = new GUI_Test();
        gui.tryBasic();
    }

    public void tryBasic() {
        JFrame frame = createFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("This is a button");
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(button);
        MyGUIObject guiObject = new MyGUIObject(new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 70, 100, 100), Color.red);
        panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        panel.add(guiObject,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JFrame createFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        return frame;
    }

    public class MyGUIObject extends JPanel {
        protected RectangularShape RecObj;
        protected Color myColor;

        public MyGUIObject(RectangularShape SetShape, Color setColor) {
            RecObj = SetShape;
            myColor = setColor;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setPaint(myColor);
            g2d.fill(RecObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; ..` should be `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; ..` to ensure there are no painting artifacts.

Comment: Good spot.. amended. Otherwise was fine.

Comment: (scratches head) Not sure why I made that comment here than on the OP (must have got turned around as to where I was).  In any case, hopefully I've now communicated that to at least two people - the OP and you, and you are already helping out other people so even more might get to hear it (in time)  +1 for the answer and edit..